# Is an SQS needed with a Lambda in this use case?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, architecture, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to build a flow that allows a user to enter data and it's being stored in RDS. My question is do I need to go from USER -> SQS -> Lambda -> RDS to or is it better to go straight from USER -> Lambda -> RDS which skips the queue entirely. Are there going to be scalability issues with the latter?

I do like that the SQS can retry a large number of times to guarantee the data, but is there a similar way to retry with a lambda alone? It's important that all of the data is stored and done so in a timely manner. I'm struggling to see the tradeoffs of the two scenarios.

If anyone has any input on the situation, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there going to be scalability issues with the latter?

It depends on multiple metrics including traffic, spikes, size of the database, rpm etc.

Putting SQS before lambda provides you to manage number of database queries in t time according to your needs. It is a "queue" and you are consuming that queue. In some business cases it may not be useful(banking transactions etc) but in some cases(analytic calculations) it may be helpful. Instead of making a single insert whenever lambda is invoked, you can set `batch size` and insert in [batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)(10 records at once) which reduces the number of queries.

Also you can define `dead letter queue` to push your problematic data(couldn't make it to database). It will be another queue that you to check later to identify problematic inputs. The document can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/robust-serverless-application-design-with-aws-lambda-dlq/)

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, I never really considered batching as an option!

Comment: @NickK batch is helpful for scaling, another alternative would be kinesis. we use kinesis in front of some of our lambdas - collecting analytical data and it is possible to define 10.000 very helpful for scaling.

Comment: From the perspective of spikes occurring, would you say that the Lambda alone could run into issues of having a slowed performance? One detail I forgot to mention was that my requests are very dense during certain parts of the day, and almost non-existent during other times of the day. Would the SQS help scale to handle spikes? Thanks again!

Comment: @NickK I don't think lambda will face performance problems, you may increase memory if you are doing some memory consuming operations. Apart from that sqs will not cause problem - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-quotas.html there is no quota/limit related to your use cases.

Comment: @NickK https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/ this document also has some useful information and some comparison with kinesis. It may be helpful.